# Редактирование изображения в реальном времени

Tags: php, изображения, javascript

Что можно использовать для редактирования изображения в реальном времени, когда грузится фотография и вводимый в поле текст, тут же отображается на фотографии.
Есть какие-то для того мощные инструменты?

Comment: Ничего не понял. Причем тут js? Фотография куда грузится на сервер или наоборот? Если на сервер - file-api+canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.moxiemanager.com/  посмотри в демках images-> edit images